# Groovy Dependency Injection

Tags: java, grails, groovy, dependency-injection

I want to inject a Log4j Logger (or in case of generality any class) into all my classes that has a log property:

```
def log
```

This is done in Grails automatically. I want to have the same feature in ordinary groovy apps, lets say for all groovy files under `src`.
The speciality with Log4j is, that the logger needs to know the class which to log. (`Logger.getLogger(Class clazz)`)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you seen the `@Log` [annotation added](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2010/09/20/log-groovys-new-and-extensible-logging-conveniences/) in Groovy 1.8?

Comment: Awesome! I must have missed that. You guys really do a good job there! Thx.

Comment: Actually, at the time of writing this, the annotation for log4j and slf4j [seems](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5557) to be [broken](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5574) in Groovy 2.0...

Comment: Had a look into it, and it seems to be a classpath issue..  so long as log4j is on the classpath when the scripts are executed, the annotation should work fine :-D

Answer (score 4):

Groovy provides native support for this using the [`@Log4j` annotation](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2010/09/20/log-groovys-new-and-extensible-logging-conveniences/) on the class.  This creates a `log` field pointing to the Log4J Logger with the same name as the class in question, i.e.:

```
package com.example
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j

@Log4j
public class LogExample {
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
package com.example
public class LogExample {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogExample.class)
}
```